# Git and SFTP - How to separate them?

Tags: ssh, git, sftp

We have a local development server with Ubuntu 14.04.
We use SFTP with vsftp, and Git.

Some coworkers have access over SFTP (without ssh access, `/usr/bin/nologin` and sftponly group), and other coworkers have access to Git host (different username, shell as `/usr/bin/git-shell`).

I want to create the following environment: SFTP access for web front-end developer (external coworkers) and Git access (over ssh://) for our back-end developer (internal or external coworkers).

SFTP user is chrooted, and this works perfectly.

The Problem is with Git - if users have access via ssh:// to the git repository they at the same time have access for all system directories via SFTP.

How to use SFTP and Git in the same system without SFTP access for Git users?

PS.
I read almost whole Google results, but solutions don't work or are so old or advise turn off SFTP.

Comment: Try using a ForceCommand, and use the git-shell for the command as well. ForceCommand disables sftp unless set to internal-sftp.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated post:**

Using the following `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config` for your (otherwise normal) user should work:

```
ForceCommand /usr/bin/git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

This magic little command was originally found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/256743/393211).  Note that the user's shell must be a normal fully featured shell in order for this to work properly.

**Reason for edit:**

I just realized my initial answer didn't actually work for me (*so embarrassing*).  Sure it disables SFTP, but it seems to prevent git from working properly as well!

**Original post:**

> Try using a ForceCommand, and use the git-shell for the command as well. ForceCommand disables sftp unless set to internal-sftp. - [muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581625/git-and-sftp-how-to-separate-them#comment806284_581625)

Just decided to quote [muru's](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581625/git-and-sftp-how-to-separate-them#comment806284_581625) so that others might benefit from it.  It works like a charm.

I was having the exact same issue, and almost missed this gem since it was in the comments instead of posted as an answer.